# Entity Framework: context.add() always adds duplicate entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to do a simple add operation but every time I add a new record in my Access table, it adds two records, no matter which way I try to add.

Here is my Access Class:

```
    public partial class Access
    {
        public Access()
        {
            this.Rights = new HashSet<Right>();
        }

        public int AccessId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Right> Rights { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my DBContext:

```
    public partial class UserManEntities : DbContext
{
    public UserManEntities()
        : base("name=UserManEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Access> Accesses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Right> Rights { get; set; }
}
```

Now my database has a one to many relationship ACCESS to RIGHT

```
            using (var db = new UserManEntities())
            {
                Access newObject = new Access(){name=newUser, type="user"};
                db.Accesses.Add(newObject);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

My results are that I have two rows in the Access table with the exact same name.  I don't understand why it is adding double.    Can someone please steer me in the right direciton?

Comment: This is something that puzzles every EF developer sooner or later. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I did read that article but that, and every other article I read, focus on the situation where you insert a new Access entry with an existing Right entry and the Right entry is duplicated.  My issue is, I'm adding a new Access entry without any Right entry and my Access entry is duplicated.

Comment: @GertArnold:  Based on the article I tried attaching a blank Right because I'm not trying to associate a Right with the current Access:                      'db.Entry(newObject).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                    db.Rights.Attach(new Right());
                    db.SaveChanges();'   But it is still inserting duplicate Access entries

Comment: Oh well, you're adding the same Access twice. For EF it's just a new record. Why don't you just skip everything about rights in your question? They don't play any role here (which I missed at first glance). Is your code supposed to update an existing Access?

Comment: @GertArnold.  Ok I removed extra code about rights.  I don't care about the rights table I was just trying to give a total picture.  Can you please explain how I'm adding it twice?  My code is just supposed to add 1 new entry into the access database.  That is all I want.

Comment: All I see is one statement that adds and `Access` record to the database. Do you mean that somehow the statement runs twice?

Comment: Yes exactly.  That is what was happening and it was driving me crazy.  I believe it had to do with the autocompleteextender I was using.  I narrowed it down to that control causing the issue and I wasn't able to figure out why it was producing that behavior, but I adjusted the code for that control and now it adds only one entry.  So my initial assumption of the Entity Framework messing up was wrong.  Thanks for your help.